# CSS: Menu Dropdown showing horizontally when I need vertical

Tags: html, css

I am working on a navigational menu. I have a problem with the dropdown submenus. When I hover over the submenu, it shows the entries horizontally, but I want it vertically. Can someone please show me what I can do to fix it? Thanks.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gp9rr/).

Here is my CSS code:

```
#nav                            {overflow:hidden;
                                 margin:0px auto;
                                 text-align:center;}

#nav ul li                      {display:inline-block;
                                 list-style:none;
                                 vertical-align:top;
                                 width:100px;}

#nav>ul>li>a>img                {text-align:center;
                                 width:100px;
                                 height:100px;}

#nav a                          {text-decoration:none !important;}

#nav a:hover                    {text-decoration:underline !important;}

#nav > ul > li > ul             {display:none;
                                 z-index:999;
                                 position:absolute;}

#nav li:hover ul                {display:block;}

.submenu li                     {border-bottom:solid 1px #333333;
                                 font-size:12px;}

.submenu img                    {display:inline;
                                 vertical-align:middle;
                                 width:25px;
                                 height:25px;
                                 float:left;
                                 margin:5%}

.submenu li:hover               {background-color:#CCC;}
```

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="">
                <img src="images/placeholder.png">
                Home
            </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="">
                <img src="images/placeholder.png">
                Menu w/ Submenu
            </a>
      <ul class="submenu">
                <li>
                <a href="">
                <img src="images/placeholder.png">
                Submenu Item
                </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                <a href="">
                <img src="images/placeholder.png">
                Submenu Item
                </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
            <a href="">
                <img src="images/placeholder.png">
                Menu Item
            </a>
            </li>

            <li>
            <a href="">
                <img src="images/placeholder.png">
                Menu Item
            </a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to comment `position:absolute;` in your submenu.

```
#nav > ul > li > ul {display:none;
            z-index:999;
            /* position:absolute;*/}
```

Check this in action:

### http://jsfiddle.net/5Kjg4/

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the solution to you problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Gp9rr/2/)
You just had to add `display:block` and `float` to your submenu `li`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gp9rr/1/)

You have css class `#nav ul li` which makes sub menu align horizonatally..

one way to solve this is using `!important property and ovveriding display property`.

Better solution would be using psuedo classes

```
#nav ul li:not(.subItem)            {display:inline-block;
                                 list-style:none;
                                 vertical-align:top;
                                 width:100px;}
.subItem{
     display:block;

}
```

this way inline-block is not applied to subItems.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to you css

> // if you need position: absolute

```
#nav ul li ul li {
float: left; // float left for inner li
display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul li ul  {
    width: 100px; // set width for you'r ul
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following css in your code and it should work fine.
Problem was that you are displaying inline-block for all `ul li`.

Take a look at fiddle **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gp9rr/5/)**

```
#nav  ul  li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100px;
}
```

**To**

```
#nav > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100px;
}
```